# Error by getting date from database with RowMapper

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, mapping

I'm getting an error when I try to recover date form database. If I comment the line it works fine. Any idea?

The value of date in database is `00000-00-00 00:00:00`, and connection is well.

```
public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return jdbc.query("select * from t_task", new RowMapper<Task>() {

        public Task mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Task task = new Task();

            task.setId(rs.getLong("idTask"));
            task.setDate(rs.getDate("date")); //Error here

            return task;
        }

    });
}
```

It returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: StatementCallback; SQL [select * from t_task]; Value '9oneoned00000-00-00 00:00:00�11111�2014-02-04 21:13:31
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
    at com.javalabs.web.model.TaskDao.getTasks(TaskDao.java:25)
    at com.javalabs.web.test.App.main(App.java:24)
```

**t_task**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTask`.`t_task` (
  `idTask` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  `pending` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `deadline` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `idTaskCategory` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idTaskPriority` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `idTaskState` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `idUser` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `idUser_responsible` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `evaluation` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: What is the type of the field in the database?

Comment: Which package date u import in Task class ?

Comment: database type is Datetime, and in Task class I import java.util.Date

Comment: I've changed the date from 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to 2014-01-01 00:00:00 and now it worked. Maybe mysql initialized bad datetime :(